# function for ```model += constraint_lhs == constraint_rhs``` in pulp python

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I'm solving an LP using pulp. I want to add constraints to my model.
Most friendly way is :

```
model += lhs == rhs
```

When we want to add constraints using `apply` method in `pandas.DataFrame`, since lambda methods don't take `+=` sign in them, we need to do something like this:

```
df['variable'].apply(lambda x: model.__iadd__(lhs==rhs))
```

Now, I don't want to use `__iadd__()` method directly, rather I want to make a function for this.
What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
`expression is our constraint`: lhs == rhs

def add_to_model(model, expression):
    return model.__iadd__(expression)
```

An example:

```
def add_to_model(model, x==0)
    return model.__iadd__(x==0)
```

Because in the above function, `expression` variable will be treated as `Boolean`, this is not serving the purpose. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: "*def add_to_model(model, x==0)*"  An expression as formal parameter? Not sure what that means. Must be a novel concept.

Comment: Expressions can't be lazily evaluated. You could store the expressions as strings and `eval()` them as you say, but it's not really clear why you want to store boolean expressions. They will always just evaluate to `True` or `False` so why not use those booleans? The effect is adding 1 or 0 to your model, but that doesn't seem particularly useful -- so it's not really clear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @ddejohn == is overloaded. Operator overloading allows PuLP to work. Instead of evaluating its builds a data structure that can be used to generate the complete LP/MIP later on.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you should use LpProblem.addConstraint() to do this

https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/d1ab490c156a7932aca44cfd346ec754fdda96bc/pulp/pulp.py#L1643